# Installing NCTUNS in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-center, software-sources, 13.10

I am not able to find the NCTUNS tool in the Ubuntu Software Center.
How to install the NCTUNS on the Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

The NCTUns is a network simulator and emulator. Each version adheres to only a selected GNU/Linux distribution of fedora (The latest NCTUns 6.0 adhering to fedora 12).